# PHP table query display front end

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys im working on querying a mysql table and displaying results in front end using php. But im failing to filter the data by user i.e I only want to show the results based on the current user ID.

database connection

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ('*******', '******', '*******', '******');

$current_user = get_user_id();
$sql = "SELECT Results FROM `assessments` where User_ID = current_user";

      if ( value < 50 ) {
    echo "You need to improve";

    } else {
        echo " Good Work ";

}
```

My table is like the following

```
User_ID                 Results
20                      59
27                      47
28                      60
30                      60
```

Comment: are you missing **$** in current_user variable? You code is buggy, first clear your syntactical bugs, then post it

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a $ before current_user. Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT Results FROM `assessments` where User_ID = $current_user";
```

Comment: This fixes the issue. I also want to warn you if you can be sure that `$current_user` is always an integer. If the end user has any way of sending it as a string, you will get SQL errors and be at risk of SQL injection attacks.